# Unable to log in to Ambari UI - NPE\500 Server Error

Tags: hadoop, ambari

I have installed ambari-server 2.2.0 on CentOS 7 using all default responses to ambari-server setup.

I have not added new users, nor have I changed the password of 'admin' from the default.

I was able to login to the UI initially, and use the REST API to submit blueprints and cluster. The cluster was created correctly and all installed hadoop services are running fine. The stack is HDP 2.3.

However, after a few days, I am no longer able to log in to the Ambari UI. When I land on the login page and try to login as 'admin', I see the following message:

```
Unable to connect to Ambari Server. Confirm Ambari Server is running and you can reach Ambari Server from this machine.
```

When I check /var/log/ambari-server/ambari-server.log I see the following stack trace:

```
29 Feb 2016 11:18:17,234  WARN [qtp-ambari-client-23] ServletHandler:563 - /api/v1/users/admin
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.internal.ActiveWidgetLayoutResourceProvider.getResources(ActiveWidgetLayoutResourceProvider.java:153)
        at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.internal.ClusterControllerImpl$ExtendedResourceProviderWrapper.queryForResources(ClusterControllerImpl.java:945)
        at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.internal.ClusterControllerImpl.getResources(ClusterControllerImpl.java:132)
        at org.apache.ambari.server.api.query.QueryImpl.doQuery(QueryImpl.java:508)
        at org.apache.ambari.server.api.query.QueryImpl.queryForSubResources(QueryImpl.java:463)
        at org.apache.ambari.server.api.query.QueryImpl.queryForResources(QueryImpl.java:436)
        at org.apache.ambari.server.api.query.QueryImpl.execute(QueryImpl.java:216)
        at org.apache.ambari.server.api.handlers.ReadHandler.handleRequest(ReadHandler.java:68)
        at org.apache.ambari.server.api.services.BaseRequest.process(BaseRequest.java:135)
        at org.apache.ambari.server.api.services.BaseService.handleRequest(BaseService.java:106)
        at org.apache.ambari.server.api.services.BaseService.handleRequest(BaseService.java:75)
        at org.apache.ambari.server.api.services.UserService.getUser(UserService.java:68)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$ResponseOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:205)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:540)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:715)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1496)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.apache.ambari.server.security.authorization.AmbariAuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AmbariAuthorizationFilter.java:196)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:201)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1467)
        at org.apache.ambari.server.api.MethodOverrideFilter.doFilter(MethodOverrideFilter.java:72)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1467)
        at org.apache.ambari.server.api.AmbariPersistFilter.doFilter(AmbariPersistFilter.java:47)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1467)
        at org.apache.ambari.server.security.AbstractSecurityHeaderFilter.doFilter(AbstractSecurityHeaderFilter.java:109)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1467)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.UserAgentFilter.doFilter(UserAgentFilter.java:82)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.GzipFilter.doFilter(GzipFilter.java:294)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1467)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:501)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:429)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
        at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.AmbariHandlerList.processHandlers(AmbariHandlerList.java:216)
        at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.AmbariHandlerList.processHandlers(AmbariHandlerList.java:205)
        at org.apache.ambari.server.controller.AmbariHandlerList.handle(AmbariHandlerList.java:139)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:971)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1033)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:696)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:53)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I really need to know how to recover from this. The hadoop services are all running fine for now, but I need the Ambari UI for management\alerts, etc. I would like to not have to recreate cluster as it is already in use.

**EDIT**

I should add that I am still able to make REST API requests directly using an app like POSTMAN, or curl. for instance: /api/v1/clusters/{name}  returns the correct information when using admin\admin as the auth.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to recover, though I still don't know what caused the issue.

Looking at the 'user' table in postgresql, the 'active_widget_layouts' column had a value like this:

```
"[{"id":"8"},{"id":"9"},{"id":"10"}]"
```

But when I looked at the 'widget_layout' table, the lowest id in the table was 11. This is what was causing the NPE in the original post. After I changed the 3 values in that field to 11, 12 and 13 respectively, I was able to log into the UI without issue.

Again, I do not know how to reproduce the issue. I don't know what occurred that would have caused that to happen. But at least I was able to recover.